# Serial port under-runs occurring even though code is built to try and keep Tx buffer full.

Tags: c#, serial-port

OK, Here's the deal. I am using the serial port to modulate an LED light array (making the array dimmable). Problem is the array flashes periodically, a quick flash every 2-4 seconds.

I use a System.Timer to check the Tx buffer state every 10 mS. If the buffer doesn't have a minimum number of characters pending, the routine adds more. In theory the buffer should never run out of characters, but it does, aka LED array flashes. I detect and count these events, so I know under-runs are occurring. Furthermore, I measure the time taken to refill the buffer and it sometimes takes over 1000 mS to add more characters. TxBuffer size is set to 4096, and my desired buffer count is 2000. For the life of me I don't get why the serial port blocks for as long as a second when in theory it shouldn't block at all...

Setup code:

```
charsSent = 0;
myPort.PortName = commPort;
myPort.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding ();
myPort.BaudRate = 19200;
myPort.DataBits = 8;
myPort.Parity = Parity.None;
myPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
myPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
myPort.DtrEnable = false;
myPort.RtsEnable = false;
myPort.ReadTimeout = 500;   // SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;
myPort.WriteTimeout = 500;  // SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;

myPort.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
myPort.WriteBufferSize = 4096;

myPort.Open ();
```

Timer code:

```
myPort.BreakState = false;
int txBufferCount = myPort.BytesToWrite;
if (txBufferCount == 0)
    ++underRuns;
// refill the xmit buffer if needed...
int bytesNeeded = (txBufferCount > MaxTxLoadCount) ? 0 : MaxTxLoadCount - txBufferCount;
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
while (bytesNeeded > 0)
{
    myPort.Write (charbuf, 0, 5);
    charsSent += 5;
    bytesNeeded -= 5;
}
if (DateTime.Now - start > maxWriteTime)
    maxWriteTime = DateTime.Now - start;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the relationship between this 4KB "Tx buffer" and the actual UART TXD register?  Does the UART have a Tx FIFO?  Is the output data rate and/or consumption from this "Tx buffer" supposed to be continuous and steady?

Comment: Unsure about the actual UART buffer sizes, under windows all of that is suppose to be abstracted away. In my usage case there is not a UART on the far end. I am just using the serial port to create a variable duty cycle pulse width which is then used as the control signal to drive an array of LEDs.

Comment: After screwing with it some more it appears that the driver in the PC periodically forces the write methods to block until the physical UART Txbuffer is empty, even though the SW buffer has plenty of room to spare. So my LEDs go off until my free running timer routing triggers again and I refill the buffer, resulting in a "flicker". Its too bad the driver doesn't have an event to signal TxBuffer empty like the hardware most likely does...

Comment: It does, WaitCommEvent on EV_TXEMPTY.  It isn't exposed by SerialPort, nobody really needs it.  The actual problem is surely the driver, probably a USB emulator which tends to be very flakey.

Comment: Ah, someone you still see's it as signals on traces. Even though the traces only exist at the sub-micron scale, and are running between two cut-and-paste sections of an IC...

Answer (score 0):

For my usage I found a workaround. Basically I allow for two instances of my timer service route to exists at any one time. Furthermore I protect the buffer refill code with a lock, so that while one instance is inside the lock section (and being held up by the bull shit blocking write) the other is being held just outside of the lock section by the lock.

Net result is that as soon as the instance being write blocked, unblocks and exits the lock section, the other instance enters the lock and refills the buffer. Net net the LEDs might still be flashing (depending upon exactly when the driver unblocks (UART's Txbuffer = empty, vs. UART's TxShiftRegister = empty).

It's just now you can't see them do it, so end the end it works for me...

cheers,

Keith